# How to make the text file content appear on Command Prompt using C coding via VS2012

Tags: c, text

I am trying to create a text-based program.

I need that program to show whatever I put in a .txt into the command prompt.

*The program is text-based game that runs on command prompt wherein in the beginning, if the user keys in the necessary command to see the Intro of the game, the program (running on command prompt) will show the Intro story I have typed in the .txt file.

This will be coded by using C language via Visual Studio 2012

Does anyone know the code for this?

*Additional Details:

I am looking for the code to be put into the C code.
Like

```
if (user wants to read File 1)
{
PUT THE CODE HERE!

printf("Go to previous page?(1)")
scanf("%d",&previouspage);
if (previouspage==1)
{
Go to Previous page
}

}
```

---

Output on Command Prompt:

The content of File 1....

Go to Previous Page?(1)

Comment: use **TYPE "path to file"** . Refer to this http://www.robvanderwoude.com/type.php

Comment: Are you really using **DOS** or are you referring to the commandline in Windows?

Comment: My bad! Misunderstood the definition of DOS. T,T Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TYPE command is used to display contents of a text file.

```
TYPE "C:\textfile.txt"
```

Refer to this [link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/type.php) for more details.

Comment: Is there other way for me to write that code as a C language?

Answer (score 0):

check the `TEE` port here:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/unixports.php

it will split output to console and to file simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

This command shows a text file in a Windows prompt and MS-DOS window.

```
type c:\file.txt
```